# When using NginX as a reverse proxy, how can i fallback to a maintenance url?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have setup Nginx in front of two IIS servers.  The main goal is to load balance, ssl offload, and cache static content.

What i am having a really tough time with is showing a maintenance page when all the Upstream servers are either unavailable or throwing 404 errors.  I have created a maintenance.html file on my NginX box but cannot get it to load.  I can sometimes get it to load IIS 404s, and sometimes get it to load the default NginX 404.  What I am really trying to do is if for some reason all the upstreams are down or throwing 404s is to show the user a "Maintenance" page and eventually put in some code in that page to alert me that all the upstream servers have gone down.

Here is my Configuration:

```
# -------------------------------------------
#       ACTUAL SITE WITH - SSL CERTIFICATE
#------------------------------------------


# Backend IIS Servers
upstream backend-iis {

    # Health Checks
    #healthcheck_enabled; 
    #healthcheck_delay 5000; 
    #healthcheck_timeout 5000; 
    #healthcheck_failcount 1; 

    # Upstream Servers
        server ww1.pickle.com  max_fails=3  fail_timeout=31s;
        server ww2.pickle.com  max_fails=3  fail_timeout=31s;
        #server ww3.pickle.com;

      # Sticky Sessions
      #sticky;
      #ip_hash;

}


# Server Configuration
server {

    # Server Specific Settings
       server_name        www.pickle.com;
       access_log         /var/log/nginx/www.pickle.com.log ;
       keepalive_timeout  5;
       allow              all;
       server_tokens      off; 
       gzip               on;
       gzip_vary          on;

    # SSL Settings (with SPDY 2)
       ssl on;
       listen 443 ssl spdy; 
       ssl_certificate /usr/share/nginx/ssl-certs/pickle_com/pickle_basic.crt;
    #  ssl_certificate /usr/share/nginx/ssl-certs/pickle_com/pickle_ev.crt;
       ssl_certificate_key        /usr/share/nginx/ssl-certs/pickle_com/pickle.com.key;
       ssl_session_timeout        15m;
       ssl_protocols              SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
       ssl_ciphers                RC4:HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
       ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;
       ssl_session_cache          shared:SSL:10m;




    # Proxy Pass to: backend-iis
    location / {

             #root               /usr/share/nginx/sites/pickle-down/;

         # Proxy Header to Keep Ip Address and Hostname
         proxy_redirect    off;
         proxy_set_header  Host              "www.pickle.com";
         proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

         # Proxy Pass to Backend IIS Servers
         proxy_pass             http://backend-iis;
         # proxy_next_upstream    error timeout http_404;
         proxy_temp_path        /usr/share/nginx/temp;

         #Intercept Proxy Errors (show Nginx Error Pages)
         #proxy_intercept_errors on; 
                 error_page 404 500 502 503 504 = @maintenance;

    }


    # Proxy Pass to: backend-iis
    location @maintenance {
         internal;
         root        /usr/share/nginx/sites/pickle-down;
         index  maintenance.html index.html index.htm;
         allow all;

    }



   error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
   location = /50x.html {
   root html;
  }

   error_page 404 /404.html;
   location = /usr/share/nginx/sites/pickle-down/404.html {
   root html;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you using the free version ?

I think what you are looking for is in the non-free version called  [NGINX Plus](http://nginx.com/products/).

- [Advanced Load Balancing](http://nginx.com/products/advanced-load-balancing/)
- [Application Health Checks](http://nginx.com/products/application-health-checks/)

Comment: Actually got it to work with the free version.  Had to do a custom build with a few extras.  Here is a bash script i have which solves the issue.  You might have to modify it because the bash script also does a few extras such as creating custom directories we always use. 

https://github.com/villanus/nginx/blob/master/bash/install-nginx-custom.sh